# How to Detect Low-Performance Android Devices for Conditional Animation Rendering?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-lottie

I am developing an Android application using Jetpack Compose, which incorporates heavy animations and Lottie files. The app runs smoothly on high-performance devices like the Pixel 6 or 7. However, I aim to optimize the app's performance on lower-end devices by disabling these heavy animations and replacing Lotties with static images.

What would be an effective strategy to conditionally enable or disable these resource-intensive animations based on the actual device performance?

Initially, I considered using the Android API level as a metric for determining device performance. However, many new devices with the latest Android API (13) still exhibit poor performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Android documentation mentions the [Performance Class Standard](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/performance-class)

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of which is over internet as Telegram `DevicePerformanceClass`. Here are three categories and by using these you can switch your animation.

```
public class SharedConfig {

    private static int devicePerformanceClass;
    
    public final static int PERFORMANCE_CLASS_LOW = 0;
    public final static int PERFORMANCE_CLASS_AVERAGE = 1;
    public final static int PERFORMANCE_CLASS_HIGH = 2;

    public static int getDevicePerformanceClass() {
        if (devicePerformanceClass == -1) {
            int androidVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            int cpuCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
            int memoryClass = ((ActivityManager) ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();
            int totalCpuFreq = 0;
            int freqResolved = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < cpuCount; i++) {
                try {
                    RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu%d/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq", i), "r");
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    if (line != null) {
                        totalCpuFreq += Utilities.parseInt(line) / 1000;
                        freqResolved++;
                    }
                    reader.close();
                } catch (Throwable ignore) {}
            }
            int maxCpuFreq = freqResolved == 0 ? -1 : (int) Math.ceil(totalCpuFreq / (float) freqResolved);

            if (androidVersion < 21 || cpuCount <= 2 || memoryClass <= 100 || cpuCount <= 4 && maxCpuFreq != -1 && maxCpuFreq <= 1250 || cpuCount <= 4 && maxCpuFreq <= 1600 && memoryClass <= 128 && androidVersion <= 21 || cpuCount <= 4 && maxCpuFreq <= 1300 && memoryClass <= 128 && androidVersion <= 24) {
                devicePerformanceClass = PERFORMANCE_CLASS_LOW;
            } else if (cpuCount < 8 || memoryClass <= 160 || maxCpuFreq != -1 && maxCpuFreq <= 2050 || maxCpuFreq == -1 && cpuCount == 8 && androidVersion <= 23) {
                devicePerformanceClass = PERFORMANCE_CLASS_AVERAGE;
            } else {
                devicePerformanceClass = PERFORMANCE_CLASS_HIGH;
            }
            if (BuildVars.LOGS_ENABLED) {
                FileLog.d("device performance info (cpu_count = " + cpuCount + ", freq = " + maxCpuFreq + ", memoryClass = " + memoryClass + ", android version " + androidVersion + ")");
            }
        }

        return devicePerformanceClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems to do exactly what I am looking for!